# How to get DbSet<SomeClass> (EF) from the dbContext using reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection

Let's say that I have

```
DBContext principal = new DBContext();
var x = principal.GetType().GetProperty("SomeClass").GetType();
```

I now have the PropertyInfo of DbSet< SomeClass >

What I'm trying to do now is somehow iterate (convert to list for example) and get the values from each row in the table.

imagine I could do this:

```
x[0] // would be the 0th entery in DbSet<SomeClass>, the first row aka of type SomeClass
```

From here I would know how to further drill down and access properties (using the same principle as above)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you using reflection instead of generics, like the `DbContext.Set<T>()` method?

Comment: Because I'm trying to create my own custom ValidationAttribute and in the constructor I'm sending Type class as a parameter. If it was a function I'd use generics but I cant write something like public Constructor<T>

Comment: Use `DBContext.Set<T>`? It's been a while since I've used EF but I'm pretty sure there was a generic way that accepts a type.

Comment: Are you sure you want to access the database from within an attribute?

Comment: var myName = principal.set<MyClass>().ToList()[0].FirstName;
ConsoleWriteline(x); should work in theory then but I get stuck in an infinite loop for some reasons @JeroenVannevel

Comment: The database got stuck somehow. I confirm your comment as the answer, could you please post it so I can upvote, you helped me out a lot @JeroenVannevel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DbSet implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>,` so something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace efAW
{
    class Program
    {

        static IEnumerable GetAllMembers(DbContext db, string dbSetName)
        {
            var pi = db.GetType().GetProperty(dbSetName);
            return (IEnumerable)pi.GetValue(db);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new aw())
            {
                var customers = GetAllMembers(db, "Customers").OfType<Customer>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

David