# Dynamic Property to list in c# from reflection

Tags: c#

I want to convert following to list. I have fetched property using reflection, but how to convert them to list (in my case this is entity object DBSet).

and I need the result as list.

```
ClassObject.GetType().GetProperty(classname) //After getting property I need it in .ToList()
```

Comment: Why do you want a list with a single element?

Comment: what are you converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert with a function like this.

If the reflected object is not enumerable, it can't be converted.

```
public static List<T> ConvertMysteriousObjectToList<T>(object input)
{
    var enumerable = input as IEnumerable;
    if (enumerable == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("The object is not convertible to a list.");
    return enumerable.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

If you're trying to convert some flavor of DbSet (e.g. a `DbSet<Foo>`) then you'd call it like this:

```
var o = ClassObject.GetType().GetProperty(classname);
var list = ConvertMysteriousObjectToList<Foo>(o);
```

If you don't know the type:

```
var list = ConvertMysteriousObjectToList<object>(o);
```

or

```
var list = ConvertMysteriousObjectToList<dynamic>(o);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have "Foo" at compile time.

Comment: Then I guess you'll need a `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`. The code I provided will still work for those types.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted.

```
static IEnumerable GetAllMembers(DbContext db, string dbSetName)
        {
            var pi = db.GetType().GetProperty(dbSetName);
            return (IEnumerable)pi.GetValue(db);
        }
```

source:
[How to get DbSet<SomeClass> (EF) from the dbContext using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880099/how-to-get-dbsetsomeclass-ef-from-the-dbcontext-using-reflection)